# Sort a container.Map according to values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, csv, plot, cell-array

I have a container.Map that holds the name of a strategy (string) and the number of consecutive rounds said strategy was present in a simulation (double). I would like to plot the maximum number of consecutive rounds every strategy was present in the simulation **in ascending order**.

Below is a the code I am using, as well as a small sample of a csv-file which has the format: (`simulation round`, `if present: number of occurrences in the simulation`)

Each .csv-file has the following structure:

```
33061,1
33062,1
33063,1
33064,1
33065,1
33066,1
33067,1
33068,1
33069,1
33070,1
33071,1
33072,1
33073,1
43721,1
49952,1
49953,1
49954,1
49955,1
```

And the code:

```
dd = dir('*.csv');

fileNames = {dd.name}; 

data = cell(numel(fileNames),2);
data(:,1) = regexprep(fileNames, '.csv','');

for i = 1:numel(fileNames)    
   data{i,2} = dlmread(fileNames{i});
end

cc = distinguishable_colors(numel(fileNames));                % get better colormap

livedlong = containers.Map;                                   % contains all the streaks
plotC = 1;

for k = 1:numel(fileNames)

    strat = data{k,1}(10:end); % get strategy name
    XY = data{k,2};            % get data
    X = XY(:,1);               % get rounds
    Y = XY(:,2);               % get #tiles
    streak = 1;                % set streak counter to 1
    longestStreak = streak;    % set longestStreak to 1 

    %%% Calculate the streaks!
    for l = 1:(numel(X)-1)
        if ((X(l)+1) == X(l+1))
            streak = streak + 1;
            if (streak > longestStreak)
                longestStreak = streak;
            end
        else
            streak = 1;
        end
    end

    livedlong(strat)=longestStreak;              % save the streaks


end

fig2=figure();
hold on;
xlabel('Round', 'FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold');
ylabel('Strategy','FontSize',12, 'FontWeight','bold');

strategy       = keys(livedlong);
strategyStreak = values(livedlong);

[HERE I WOULD LIKE TO SORT strategyStreak W/O LOOSING THE CORRSEPONDING strategy]

for i = 1:numel(strategy)
    plot(i, sortedStrategyStreak(i), 'o', 'color', cc(i,:), 'DisplayName', sortedStrategy(i))
end
legend show;
hold off;
```

I can use cell2mat() to turn `strategyStreak` into an array, and sort it, but then I loose the correspondence with its `strategy`. Is there a way of extracting tuples: (`strategy`, `strategyStreak`) and then sort these by `strategyStreak` and pass them to plot?

Comment: [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) already returns the indices of the sorted elements in their original array. Why can't you use that to index `strategy`?

Comment: @excaza How do you mean? If I `sort` `strategy` it will not sort `strategyStreak` too, right? I need to `sort` all the values in the map while maintaining the corresponding keys -- sorting the keys won't really help.

Or am I miss understanding you?

Comment: What does `A = {'two', 'one', 'three'}; B = [2, 1, 3]; [~, idx] = sort(B); A(idx)` give you?

Comment: @excaza: It returns the appropriate 'one' 'two' 'three', but how do I transfer this to my use case, and a plot?

Comment: `strategy(idx(i))`

Comment: Just saw this, thank you for your help!